# Need help configuring MQ-like table for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a table for notifications:

```
CREATE TABLE notifications (
  id timeuuid,
  created timestamp,
  to_user_id timeuuid,
  status varchar,
  msg text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((to_user_id,status),created)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC);
```

Configured as shown above, as my 1st task is to pull by the recipient ("to_user_id" field) and the required notification status. Also, I'm puling last N records, that's why clustering order was used. This works fine.

However, I'm having issues with my 2nd task: updating notification statuses.
If I'll try to update a "status" column, it will (obviously) throw an error that a Pk part status is found in set.

OK. Thinking that my use case should follow the request, I thought of having 2 tables, 2nd looking like

```
CREATE TABLE notifications_by_id (
  id timeuuid,
  created timestamp,
  to_user_id timeuuid,
  status varchar,
  msg text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

But we hit a different issue here - my primary table is the 1st one and to update it i need "to_user_id" and "status", which are not unique and not available during update requests...

Please advise on the "best practice".
For some context - you may consider this `notifications` table as a message queue, without acks/nacks, with messages having attributes, and ability to sort by "to_user_id" and "status" fields.

Thank you!
D.

Comment: Is the to_user_id supposed to be a timeuuid?

Comment: @Nathan, can be uuid. There was an idea for time-based sorting some time ago, but did not explore it and just left timeuuid. What issue do you see  using timeuuid here? Thanks!

Comment: I do not see an issue with the type more with the data model. Here is what I would assume, each 'notification' should be unique but you are saying it is not. Why would you not set up the model that is tracking notifications to keep each notification separate? Best practice is query driven data models so which query does the notifications table serve?

Comment: @Nathan,

1. Queries:

    SELECT * FROM notifications
    WHERE to_user_id = ? AND status = ?
    LIMIT ?

and

    UPDATE notifications SET status="a"


2. Regarding uniqueness. 
Maybe I was incorrect: the messages themselves are unique items obvously, but we may have several messages with the same "to_user_id" and "status".

.. so my issue basically comes down to inability to update status in the base table using notification id.

Comment: P.S.
Just realized, maybe its the case for a materialized view as per v3.0?
I.e. have a base table with an "id" Pk and use it for my status updates, but to have a "read-only" view with a where clause filtering by "to_user_id" and "status"?

Comment: It sounds like a user can have many notifications. Can a notification have many users? Regarding the Materialized View feature I bet it would have a use for your project, especially if you would like to collect a small subset of data to query against often. This functionality could also be achieved with a `BATCH` statement and the `TTL` clause. My comments are not going to get you closer to an answer if you are looking for a best practice.

Comment: Thank you, @Nathan. Let me play around with views for now. ( Interesting to know though what the solutions could be using "classical" means. )

Answer (score 0):

You need one table with a more precise primary key. Once that is in place you can perform update/insert (each one is an UPSERT in Cassandra) on the primary key for status updates.

The table below has partition keys `user_id` and `status` with a GROUPING column `created`. This particular set up for partitioning data would be more conducive in a table geared towards users, not notifications. Why? It would help answer the question, "What are the notifications of a given status for a given user?" If the notification object could be updated by something outside of a given user's actions, the notification should have the status attribute.

```
  CREATE TABLE notifications (
  id timeuuid,
  created timestamp,
  to_user_id timeuuid,
  status varchar,
  msg text,
  --OLD LINE PRIMARY KEY ((to_user_id,status),created)
  PRIMARY KEY ((id),created)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC);
```

A second table for the notification status by user id could be created and the two kept in sync with a `BATCH` statement. Best practice is to name the tables after the query they server. `notifications_by_user` would be an appropriate table name for the second query.

As mentioned in the comment section, if you are interested in investigating the Materialized View functionality of Cassandra 3.0, check out this [Datastax blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views). Be aware that they should be understood before implemented in production. From the blog post,

> Materialized views handle automated server-side denormalization,
>   removing the need for client side handling of this denormalization and
>   ensuring eventual consistency between the base and view data. This
>   denormalization allows for very fast lookups of data in each view
>   using the normal Cassandra read path.

Hopefully this information helps you in your quest to serve data better.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

I have been always stumbling upon that "status" field as I needed both - to restrict by it and be able to update it, so I decided what if I try to remove one unknown from this my equation.

The new paradigm was to actually mimic a message query system: instead of a "status" column, I've created 3 tables aka "queues": notifications_pending, notifications_ignored, notifications_accepted. And indeed, I do not really need to read a mixed set of notifications. Rather, one status per request only. Maybe status as a column was suggested by my rdbms habits.

OK. With "status" out of my way, we have the following model:

1. 3 tables with notifications_pending serving as a queue, others - more like archives.
2. My status update actions now are a combination of 2 steps: removal from the "pending" table and insert into required status-specific tables based on the event type (accept or ignore).
3. All columns, are using clustering order desc

Please share your thoughts!

*P.S.
Sure, some new questions appear like for ex. tombstones after message "relocation", but that's def. be addressed separately.*